# Android WebView load html file from resource raw folder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am using a WebView and am trying to load a HTML file into it  which I have stored in my Resources/raw folder ( I cannot do assets because I am working with a ClassLibrary)

```
        webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/test.html");
```

What is happening is that the content of the file gets loaded in the WebView, the actual html code

This is what I see in my webview

```
<html>
<body>
    <b>TEST THISSSSS</b>
</body>
</html>
```

When what I should be seeing is

**TEST THISSSSS**

Why is this happening ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the raw resource via a stream (to string):

```
using (var stream = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.someHTMLBasedFile))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}
```

Note: Since you are loading via a resource, you can provide `res/raw-<qualifiers>` folders if you need to internationalize via the device's locale.